# Disable email sync outside working hours

Tags: email

Is there any way or a mail app where I can set a (per account) sync time? I would like the app to only ***fetch*** mails from my (work) account Mo-Fri 9-5 or if I manually sync.

I use k-9 mail since I got my first Android phone and it has a "quiet time" feature. But this seems somewhat broken in recent Android versions and I would like to have something even more aggressive if possible so I can set the app to not even download new emails from my email account at certain times.

Android version 8 (phone) and 9 (tablet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FairEmail](https://github.com/M66B/FairEmail/releases/tag/1.1072) is a popular open source Email client (crossed 100,000 downloads) which can do this for *all accounts (global)* but *not per account*. This is because of maintenance and support of app plus [battery consumption](https://github.com/M66B/FairEmail/blob/master/FAQ.md#user-content-faq39).

However, you can still use automation for [custom polling](https://github.com/M66B/FairEmail/blob/master/FAQ.md#user-content-faq78) to achieve individual account sync (this is a pro feature)

You can set the day /hour wise schedule

[image]

Developer is very active and responsive as you can see from the [XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/source-email-t3824168), which is the right place to get your questions answered.

I am an extremely satisfied user of FairEmail and not affiliated anyway with it.

Comment: The app looks really really good. It's noteworthy that this is a pro feature available in the pro version only. But I think that is fair enough and I'll probably buy it after testing the rest now.

Comment: I upvoted the community ad.

Comment: Yes, updated answer to say schedule sync is pro. Thanks